# An approach on the $abc$-conjecture

Tags: number-theory, abc-conjecture

[abc-conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture#Formulations)

> **ABC Conjecture**. For every $\varepsilon>0$, there exist only finitely many triples (a, b, c) of positive coprime integers, with a + b = c, such that:

$$c\gt\operatorname{rad}(abc)^{1+\varepsilon}$$

Obviously we are trying to get $\varepsilon$ as small as possible, but what if we let $\varepsilon=1$.

As (conjecturally) there are only a finite number of solutions, what is the maximum value of $c$ for $\varepsilon=1$?

Or, if this is still too hard, find $C_{max}$ for integer $\varepsilon$'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you link to goes on to define the **quality** of an $abc$-triple, to be the number $q$ such that
$$
c=\operatorname{rad}(abc)^q
$$
So looking for triples that appear when $\epsilon=1$ is tantamount to looking for triples whose quality is greater than $2$.

The triple with the largest-known quality is said to be:
$$
a=2\\
b=3^{10} \times 109\\
c=23^5
$$
which has a quality of about $1.6299$. That is, there are no known triples which satisfy the statement with $\epsilon=1$, or indeed for any $\epsilon\geq0.63$.

Comment: so the $abc$-conjecture is equivalent to $q$ being bounded from above?

Comment: different question but what is the lowest known $q$?

Comment: No, it's stronger than that. The $abc$-conjecture says that not only is $q$ bounded above, there are only a finite number of triples with $q$ larger than any number greater than $1$ (whereas just knowing that $q$ is bounded above would still permit, say, there to be infinitely many triples with $q=2$).

Comment: what's wrong with $q=1$? - most i try, e.g. 2,3,5, have $q\lt1$

Comment: Yeah, most of the time $q<1$. You can construct infinite families with $q>1$ if you're clever, but always $q$ will tend to $1$ as the numbers get larger. (At least, assuming the conjecture is true...)

Comment: (Oh, and as for the lowest known $q$: certainly $q>\frac{1}{3}$ for all triples, as $\operatorname{rad}(abc)\leq abc \leq c^3$. You should be able to get as close to this as you like by taking all three of $a,b,c$ to be large and square-free, but I don't quite have a rigorous proof of this; you'd probably have good results asking it as a separate question.)

Comment: i'll look into it. how do you get $q=1$?

Comment: The only $abc$-triple with $q=1$ is $(1,1,2)$. You should try to prove this; it's kind of a fun exercise.

Comment: well there's (1,1,3)

Comment: is it coz a,b,c are coprime?

Comment: The coprimality is a big part of it, yeah. $(1,1,3)$ doesn't work because $1+1 \neq 3$.

Comment: sorry, i forgot that bit

Comment: challenge: find another impossible $q$